# FullCalendar - None Standard Field with addEventSource

Tags: asp.net, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Getting JSON from CodeBehind with additional None Standard fields using ASP.NET.

Im getting the "standard" title,start,end,color,ClassName correctly when passing "obj" to addEventSource.

The problem is that i would like to use the "**Events**" and "**eventRender**" instead of using "**addEventSource**" to be able to handle the None Standard fields, this doesn't work.

Is it possible to pass object or JSON to "**Events**"?

I have also tried to use the "**docd**" (the none parseJSON string) not getting any results displayed in the calendar. Using FullCalendar 3

ex.

```
 events: obj, 
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        Console.log(info.event.extendedProps.PrjectID)
    }
```

This is request Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Calender.aspx/GetTimeData",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'year': year, 'month': month, 'projectID': projectid }),
                dataType: "json"

            }).done(function (doc) {
                var events = [];
                docd = doc.d;
                obj = $.parseJSON(doc.d);
              }
                 });
```

ExtraParameters:

```
ProjectID,UserID,WorkTypeID,Signed
```

Json:

```
  [{"Signed":1,"ProjectID":39,"WorkTypeid":1,"UserID":97,"id":719627,"start":"2019-01-01T07:00:00","end":"2019-01-01T15:00:00","title":"Test Title ","color":"#607d8b","className":null}]
```

********************* UPDATE 1 *********************

Edited the code, the ajax request works without any problems when implemented within the fullcalendar environment, **BUT** the posts will not appear in the calendar, also the "**eventRender**" is not triggered.

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            loading: function (bool) {
                //LoadEvents();
                //alert('events are being rendered'); // Add your script to show loading
            },
            eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
                //alert('all events are rendered'); // remove your loading 

            },
            navLinks: true,
            lazyFetching: false,
            height: "auto",
            aspectRatio: 2,
            weekends: true,
            weekNumbers: true,
            displayEventEnd: true,
            showNonCurrentDates: false,
            weekLabel: "V",
            allLocales: true,
            locale: "sv",
            header: false,
            //header: {
            //    //left: 'prev,next today',
            //    left: '',
            //    center: '',
            //    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
            //},
            viewRender: function (element, view) {
                var title = view.title;
                $("#CalendarHeadTitle").html(title);
                //element.find('.fc-title').append("-test-"); 
            },
            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
                $("#sDate, #eDate").val(moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                $('.modal').modal('show');
            },
            eventClick: function (info) {
                $('.modal').modal('show');
            },
            eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {

                //TODO: Implement - call to move!

                if (!confirm("Vill du flytta ")) {
                    revertFunc();
                }
            },

            editable: true,
            events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Calender.aspx/GetTimeData",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'year': $("#<%=DdlYear.ClientID%>").val(), 'month': $("#<%=DdlMonth.ClientID%>").val(), 'projectID': $("#<%=DdlProjects.ClientID%>").val() }),
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done(function (doc) {
                    var events = $.parseJSON(doc.d);
                    console.log(doc.d);
                    callback(events); //this provided callback function passes the event data back to fullCalendar
                });
            },
            eventRender: function (event, element) {
                console.log('event render action');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing up the syntax and functionality of fullCalendar 3 and fullCalendar 4. They are [very different](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3).

```
Console.log(info.event.extendedProps.PrjectID)
```

will fail because

a) you haven't defined an `info` variable in your function parameters (so you should be getting a Console error, although you didn't mention one), and

b) even if you fix that, I strongly suspect (based on the signature you've used for your [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventRender) function, and the fact you're making extensive use of jQuery) that you're actually using fullCalendar 3, whose [event object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object) doesn't have an "extendedProps" property.

If my assumption is correct then I would expect

```
console.log(event.ProjectID);
```

to output the required data.

---

P.S. Your code is shown somewhat out of context, so I'm not sure exactly how you're going about loading the events, but you don't need to have a process where you make an AJAX call outside the calendar environment, and then pass the resulting array to the calendar later. Instead, use one of fullCalendar's built-in features for dealing with dynamic event sources. In your case, the [events-as-a-function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function) option is probably the most suitable. 
This is the recommended way to connect your data to the calendar.

You can implement it like this:

```
events: function( start, end, timezone, callback ) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Calender.aspx/GetTimeData",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'year': year, 'month': month, 'projectID': projectid }),
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function (doc) {
    var events = $.parseJSON(doc.d);
    callback(events); //this provided callback function passes the event data back to fullCalendar
  });
}
```

FullCalendar will run this code every time it needs new events (e.g. when the calendar loads, and whenever the user changes the calendar view to cover a date range for which it hasn't already fetched events). As you can see, fullCalendar provides you with `start` and `end` dates via the callback parameters, which you can pass directly to your server to help it filter the list of events it returns to cover the date range required. Your code currently accepts "month" and "year", so could get those from the start date passed in, but if you are using anything other than "month" views then this won't be flexible enough.

Comment: Thanks, but you'll have to be more specific than "will not display". Do you get errors in your JavaScript console, maybe? I am thinking I maybe made a mistake without noticing before - `dataType: "json"` means that jQuery will parse the downloaded JSON and automatically convert it to an object. This means that (assuming `doc.d` contains an object and not a string) `$.parseJSON` should not be needed.

Comment: First check your console for errors. Then, please try changing your "done" method to the following, so it passes the data directly without additional parsing: `.done(function (doc) {
    callback(doc.d);
  });`

Comment: With both callback(events) and callback(doc.d) no error in the console, no posts in the calendar are rendered. And the   console.log('event render action'); is not triggered

Comment: Well if no events are rendered then clearly eventRender will not be triggered. Can you put `.done(function (doc) { console.log(JSON.stringify(doc)); callback(doc.d); });` please, and then paste me the result of the console.log command. Thanks.

Comment: {"d":"[{\"Signed\":1,\"ProjectID\":39,\"worktypeid\":1,\"UserID\":97,\"id\":719627,\"start\":\"2019-01-01T07:00:00\",\"end\":\"2019-01-01T15:00:00\",\"title\":\"test title\",\"color\":\"#607d8b\",\"className\":null}]"}

Comment: Right, you seem to have double-encoded your JSON. I would guess that in your server-side code you created your events, serialised them to a JSON string and then returned them, and ASP.NET then serialised _that_ into JSON (which it generally does automatically in WebMethods) wrapped in the additional object with the `d` property. There's no need to do your own JSON serialisation, just return your event array directly from the webmethod and ASP.NET will handle the serialisation for you.

Comment: Well, console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.d)) Returns:
[{\"Signed\":1,\"ProjectID\":39,\"worktypeid\":1,\"UserID\":97,\"id\":719627,\"start\":\"2019-01-01T07:00:00\",\"end\":\"2019-01-01T15:00:00\",\"title\":\"test title\",\"color\":\"#607d8b\",\"className\":null}]
Parsing $.parseJSON(doc.d); givs json-object in console.log. Using this object in events or just the doc.d as string, none will render calendar posts

Comment: Yes, `JSON.stringify(doc.d)` will just produce the same result as in your earlier comment, because it's already a string. Stringifying a string has no extra effect! Like I said, the optimal solution is to modify your server code so it doesn't double-encode, and you therefore end up with a proper array from the start. But you _could_ do `callback(JSON.parse(doc.d));` and it should work.

Comment: Will fix the backend later, just want to check that the posts render ok, still the same issue with  callback($.parseJSON(doc.d)); No posts rendering and no error in console

Comment: It's pretty odd, I don't know what you're doing wrong exactly. If we test just the sample data you provided in isolation, then it works fine, here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gzc5jamn/1/ . I note that the sample event is for the January 2019...silly question but you are looking at the right time period in your calendar, and not just today's date, I hope? if that's not the issue, then it's hard to understand, maybe something about what you've told me isn't quite correct.

Comment: In fact we can even extend the demo with a call to a dummy AJAX endpoint which provides the exact JSON you showed me (just to show it's not an issue with AJAX per se), and it still works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/gzc5jamn/2/ .

Comment: We can then add in all the other fullCalendar options you've shown in your code in the question, it's still fine: http://jsfiddle.net/gzc5jamn/3/ . So I'm really a bit mystified as to why you can't see any results. The only obvious bit of difference here is the AJAX call (since I had to use a dummy endpoint). But you've told me what your AJAX endpoint is returning...so it _shouldn't_ be that...unless what you've told me about that isn't correct, or the call is occasionally failing (you'd be able to see it in the Network tools), or there's something else about your setup you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Oh and sorry here's a version logging your custom `ProjectID` field, which I think was the original point of the question! http://jsfiddle.net/mexfos16/

Comment: Well u r right. The view was not updated, with  $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', date); solved the problem. Many thx for the help!